# Count occurrences of words in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, count

I have an `ArrayList` of words with duplicate entries.

I want to count and save occurrences for each word in a data structure.

How can I do it?

Comment: Sort it, iterate over it. Or create a HashMap<String, int> iterate over the arraylist and increase the count by one each time you see the string.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you don't have a huge list of strings the shortest way to implement it is by using `Collections.frequency` method, like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("aaa");
list.add("bbb");
list.add("aaa");

Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>(list);
for (String key : unique) {
    System.out.println(key + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, key));
}
```

Output:

```
aaa: 2
bbb: 1
```

Comment: this is good if you want and know the exact word you want the frequency of, but repeating this for each word in the list...

Comment: @Yanick, yes but you can convert List to Set to know all unique words

Comment: ok, I've edited my post and added the conversion

Comment: @smas: That approach is both memory intense and inefficient at once.

Comment: @smas, finding a word frequency = O(n), converting a List into a Set = O(n), looking for each word's frequency from the Set (worst case) = O(n); that's sums up to O(2(n^2)). While an hashtable solution is O(2n) at most

Comment: @Voo I agree it's example how to implement this in the easiest and shortest way

Comment: Excellent! Works like a champ and exactly what I needed! Thanks very much for posting this!

Answer (score 13):

There are lots of possibilities. A fast to implement solution could be to use a `Map<String, Integer>` where the String is each individual word and Integer the count of each.

Traverse the list and increase the corresponding value in the map for it. In case there is no entry yet, add one with the value 1.

```
wordList = ....;

Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for(String word: wordList) {
  Integer count = wordCount.get(word);          
  wordCount.put(word, (count==null) ? 1 : count+1);
}
```

Comment: `Integer` is immutable, you **nned** to put it back in : wordCount.put(word, wordCount.get(word)++) - ok, I just saw you fixed it already :)

Comment: Already fixed it, but thanks for the hint ;)

Comment: I like a two-pass approach better - in the first pass, simply put zero into the map; in the second, add one to the value.  This avoids the sometimes confusing conditional logic, at (possibly) some slight performance cost.

Comment: IMO the "?" operator is something people should be aware of because it's widely used. But you're right, if it would have gotten more complicated than that, better use either a two-pass solution or use a proper if/else, depends on the requirements.

Comment: if Java had a null coalescing operator (??) this look even better

Answer (score 1):

Here's a test-driven class that will do what you want.  First the test:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class CounterTest extends TestCase {
    private Counter<String> counter;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        counter = new Counter<String>();
    }

    public void testInitialCountIsZero() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(0, counter.get("a"));
    }

    public void testCount() throws Exception {
        counter.count("a");
        assertEquals(1, counter.get("a"));
    }
}
```

Now the class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Counter<T> {
    private final HashMap<T, Integer> map = new HashMap<T, Integer>();

    public int get(T key) {
        final Integer n = map.get(key);
        return n == null ? 0 : n;
    }

    public void count(T key) {
        map.put(key, get(key) + 1);
    }
}
```

To solve your specific problem, you would create a counter, and iterate over your list, counting each element.

```
Counter<String> counter = new Counter<String>();
for (String string: myList)
    counter.count(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are too lazy to do it yourself (or a good industrial programmer :p), use [Multiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) from google guava.