# How to find the number of times a particular value occured in arraylist in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android applications. I created two pages i.e Page1 and Page2. Page2 contains an arraylist with repeated values. I am passing a value from page1 and
I want to find the number of occurences of the value(coming from page1) in the arraylist in page2. Please suggest what should I have been done to do that task.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collection.frequency()` is what you needed,

Try something like,

```
ArrayList<Integer> intList // your list

Set<Integer> Values = new HashSet<Integer>;
Values.addAll(intList); // all duplicates removed.

for (Integer i : Values) {

 int occurrences = Collections.frequency(intList, i);
 Log.e(i ," occurs " + occurences + " times.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

below is the solution for your problem

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.frequency(list, "Key/value to search");
```

reference link >> [how to count occurance in arraylist/list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211194/count-occurences-of-word-in-arraylist)

Answer (score 1):

Use **Collections.frequency()** method...

Eg:

```
    public class ArrFrq {

    public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();


    s.add("Vivek");
    s.add("Vicky");
    s.add("Vivek");


    System.out.println(Collections.frequency(s, "Vivek"));

    }

}
```