# How to get the number of repeated values(count) from list

Tags: java, list, collections, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to count occurrence of an element in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505928/how-to-count-occurrence-of-an-element-in-a-list)
>   [Count occurences of word in ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211194/count-occurences-of-word-in-arraylist)

Assume I have a List the following values

```
emp1, emp2, emp3, emp2, emp1, emp4, emp1
```

I need to get the number of times a string is repeated such as the following

```
emp1 - 3 times  
emp2 - 2 times  
emp3 - 1 times  
emp4 - 1 times
```

I am trying to implement this by using map. Is this the correct way or is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), which will count the number of occurrences of each value. The simplest implementation would be [`HashMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/HashMultiset.html), but you can also use a immutable implementation such as [`ImmutableMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultiset.html) if you need to keep it around.

It's as simple to use as:

```
Multiset<Item> items = HashMultiset.create(list);
System.out.println(items.count(someItem));
for (Multiset.Entry<Item> entry : items.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getElement() + " - " + entry.getCount() + " times");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options, you could use an `Map<Item, Integer>` and use the mapped value to store the frequency, this will be good for time complexity but not for space complexity.

```
for (Item i : list)
{
  Integer f = map.get(i);

  if (f == null)
    map.put(i, 1);
  else
    map.put(i, ++f);
}
```

Otherwise you could use some facility method like [`Collections.frequency(Collection<?> c, Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29) but this would be good only if you are looking for the frequency of a single element, otherwise you would need a set to check just the uniques so the first approach would be better.