# Data Structure to hold elements and respective count of each element?

Tags: java, data-structures

Is there such a java Data Structure that can store unique elements and the count of any repeated elements?

For example say I have the given data : "a", "a", "a", "b", "b" , "c" , "d"
I add each data element to this data structure and would get something similar to :

element : count
a : 3
b : 2
c : 1
d : 1

Is there a java data structure that is already made to do something similar to this?

Comment: No. But you could implement a `hashmap` and handle this.

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217438/map-for-counting-occurrences-of-the-key-in-java

Comment: Store Hashmap<K, Entry<V>> where Entry keeps int and value. Wrap hashmap's method get(V) and put(K, V) and add getElementCount(V) method.

Comment: check http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-count-duplicated-items-in-java-list/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642151/how-to-get-the-number-of-repeated-valuescount-from-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Guava has a [`Multiset`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset) type you should use for this.

```
Multiset<String> bag = LinkedHashMultiset.create();
Collections.addAll(bag, "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d");
for (Multiset.Entry<String> entry : bag.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getElement() + " : " + entry.getCount());
}
```

Choose the right `Multiset` implementation depending on which iteration order you want:

- For ordering by first insertion, use [`LinkedHashMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultiset.html) (as in my example above).
- For ordering by natural order, or by a specific comparator, use [`TreeMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html).
- If you don't care about the order, use [`HashMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultiset.html).

Obviously, these map to the same decisions you'd make for choosing a `Map` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `HashMap<String, Integer>` to do what you want.
And you can use it like so:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] data = new String[]{"a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d"};
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(String d : data) {
            Integer value = map.get(d);
            if(value == null) {
                map.put(d, 1);
            }
            else {
                map.put(d, value + 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Then it prints something like this:

```
{d=1, b=2, c=1, a=3}
```

Comment: The Guava Multiset approach is faster (and more semantically descriptive), so prefer that if you can use Guava. (Internally, it uses an internal `Count` class as the map value type, which is like a mutable `Integer`.)