# Count duplicate values in Multimap

Tags: java, count, guava, multimap

I have Multimap. Example:

```
00254=[00255, 2074E, 2074E, 2074E, 2074E, 2074E, 2074E, 00010, 00010, 00010, 0006, 0006, 0006, 00010, R01018, R01018, 0006, 0006, R01018, R01018, R01018, 12062, S2202962, S2202962, R01018, 12062, 20466, 12062, 20466, 22636, 20466, 20466, 22636, 22636, 22636, 22636, 22636, 22636, 22636, 22636, 00255, 2074E, 2074E, 2074E, 2074E, 2074E]
00256=[00257, 2074E, 2074E, 2074E, 2074E, 00010, 2074E, 2074E, 0006, 00010, 00010, 00010, 0006, 0006, 0006, R01018, R01018, 0006, R01018, R01018, R01018, 12062, S2202962, S2202962, R01018, 12062, 20466, 12062, 20466, 20466, 20466, 22636, 22636, 22636, 22636, 22636, 22636, 22636, 22636, 22636, 00257, 2074E, 2074E, 2074E, 2074E, 00010]
```

I want to get the number of value including duplicate value.

- 00254=[00255:2, 2074E:11, 00010:4, 0006:5, R01018:6, ...]
- 00256=[00257:2, 2074E:10, 00010:5, 0006:5, R01018:7, ...]

Is it possible to get duplicate number?

Thanks.

Comment: Everything is possible. Have you tried something, do you have something to show us ? And of course, can you explain what you try to check exactly. You speak about number value but I see `R01018` ... not a 10-based number.

Comment: Thanks AxelH. I want to count the number of values. The type of data is not important. Any value can be.

Comment: Do you mean you want the count of values for a key, e.g. for key `00254` the count would be the sum of `2+11+4+5+6+...`?

Comment: Per key, iterate the value and use a `Map<YourValue, Integer>` to count. But you need to try first. That "value" is nothing but a List, so you can simply use the same logic. See [Count occurrences of words in ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5211194/4391450)

Comment: Did you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Multimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)? Perhaps `get(key).size()` is what you're looking for?

Comment: @Andreas I think OP want to "group" on the value and do a count of occurrence. I think....

Comment: @Andreas get("00254").size() is 46. I want numbers for each. e. g. 00255 is 2, 2074E is 11.

Comment: @AxelH your right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution using Java 8 Stream to get the occurrence for a specific value, simply get the `Collection` for a value, then group on the value and count (using the `Collectors` function) to get a `Map<String, Long>` :

```
Multimap<Integer, String> maps =  ArrayListMultimap.create();
maps.put(1, "foo");
maps.put(1, "bar");
maps.put(1, "foo");
maps.put(2, "Hello");
maps.put(2, "foo");
maps.put(2, "World");
maps.put(2, "World");

Here is the idea to print the occurences per value :

maps.keySet().stream() //Iterate the `keys`
            .map(i -> i + " : " +  //For each key
                        maps.get(i).stream() //stream the values.
                            .collect( //Group and count
                                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                                            Function.identity(), 
                                            Collectors.counting()
                                    )
                            )
            )
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

> 1 : {bar=1, foo=2}
>
> 2 : {Hello=1, foo=1, World=2}

This will generate a `String`, I let you adapt for your need.

Comment: I use this code. `for (String key : multimap.keySet()) {
qtyMap = multimap.get(key).stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
}` thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Counting occurrences is a perfect use case for [`Multiset`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html), which is

> A collection that supports order-independent equality, like `Set`, but may have duplicate elements. A multiset is also sometimes called a bag.
>
> Elements of a multiset that are equal to one another are referred to as occurrences of the same single element.

There are few different [`Multiset` implementations](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#implementations) you can choose from, and couple of handy [set-like methods in `Multisets` helper class](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html).

Here, you could either 1) collect to multiset or 2) use custom multimap with multiset values.

1. Instead of grouping to map, you can collect an immutable multiset:

   ```
   ImmutableMultiset<String> qtyMultiset = multimap.get(key).stream()
       .collect(ImmutableMultiset.toImmutableMultiset());
   ```

   or mutable one:

   ```
   HashMultiset<String> qtyMultiset = multimap.get(key).stream()
       .collect(Multisets.toMultiset(Function.identity(), e -> 1, HashMultiset::create));
   ```
2. Or maybe you can use custom multimap in the first place? (Unfortunately, there isn't any `MultisetMultimap` interface nor implementation, hence need for custom instance):

   ```
   Multimap<String, String> countingMultimap
       = Multimaps.newMultimap(new LinkedHashMap<>(), LinkedHashMultiset::create);
   ```

   You can drop `Linked` part if you don't need to preserve order. For your data:

   ```
   countingMultimap.putAll("00254", ImmutableList.of("00255", "2074E", "2074E", "2074E", "2074E", "2074E", "2074E", "00010", "00010", "00010", "0006", "0006", "0006", "00010", "R01018", "R01018", "0006", "0006", "R01018", "R01018", "R01018", "12062", "S2202962", "S2202962", "R01018", "12062", "20466", "12062", "20466", "22636", "20466", "20466", "22636", "22636", "22636", "22636", "22636", "22636", "22636", "22636", "00255", "2074E", "2074E", "2074E", "2074E", "2074E"));
   countingMultimap.putAll("00256", ImmutableList.of("00257", "2074E", "2074E", "2074E", "2074E", "00010", "2074E", "2074E", "0006", "00010", "00010", "00010", "0006", "0006", "0006", "R01018", "R01018", "0006", "R01018", "R01018", "R01018", "12062", "S2202962", "S2202962", "R01018", "12062", "20466", "12062", "20466", "20466", "20466", "22636", "22636", "22636", "22636", "22636", "22636", "22636", "22636", "22636", "00257", "2074E", "2074E", "2074E", "2074E", "00010"));
   ```

   returned multimap would be:

   ```
   {00254=[00255 x 2, 2074E x 11, 00010 x 4, 0006 x 5, R01018 x 6, 12062 x 3, S2202962 x 2, 20466 x 4, 22636 x 9], 00256=[00257 x 2, 2074E x 10, 00010 x 5, 0006 x 5, R01018 x 6, 12062 x 3, S2202962 x 2, 20466 x 4, 22636 x 9]}
   ```

For more information read [Guava Wiki page about `Multiset`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multiset) (which uses word count as an example).